# How to use checkbox in List Control

Tags: c++, mfc, listcontrol

hi i have been working my final project about Recognition system IMEI numbers.i use c++MFC,i get the database in MySQL to the List Control and set LVS_EX_CHECKBOXES for checkbox. and i OCR the picture to number allready,if the number in Edit Control like imei in listcontrol. let the program cross in the blank.

it image project https://i.stack.imgur.com/h0Zb8.jpg
Help guide me thanks.

Comment: What exactly are you asking?

Comment: I want to know when i click button OCR and then program check auto to cross in the blank. 
and I want to know what function to use. (sry for my broken english)

Comment: So, when you click the OCR button, the checkbox should be checked?

Comment: Yes, I would like to know how.

Comment: If you are using `CCheckListBox`, it should be pretty easy http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d58s8sak.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for CListCtrl::SetCheck